# “Добавить точку” к маршруту в routePanel

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Как можно добавить кнопку "Добавить точку" как на скрине?

[image: Добавить точку]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Яндекс.Картах реализована кастомная панель маршрутов, элемент управления `routePanel` в API промежуточные точки не поддерживает.

Вы можете сделать собственный элемент управления с нужным поведением. Элемент управления должен реализовывать [интерфейс `IControl`.](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/IControl-docpage/?from=SO)

[Пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_control?from=SO) и [документация](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/controls-docpage/?from=SO#custom-control)